# How to log service calls with Proxy created by JaxWsProxyFactoryBean

Tags: jax-ws, cxf

I want to provide a component for creating a web service client. My approach so far was to extend `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean` and override the create method and provide setter and getter for parameters like timeout.

```
@Override
public synchronized Object create() {

    //do some stuff here
    Object result = super.create();
    //here too

    return result;
}
```

What ist the appropriate way to get a call to the proxy logged? I tried to set an `Interceptor` with `getInInterceptors().add(new MyInterceptor());` but `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean` only wants `PhaseInterceptor`. But I dont know how I should set all attributes on that Interceptor and if this is the right way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but its not 100% perfect.

I implemented the `LogicalHandler` Interface. Setting it to the FactoryBean and check in the handler if the message is outbound or inbound.

```
public class LoggingHandler implements LogicalHandler<LogicalMessageContext>
```

the method:

```
public boolean handleMessage(LogicalMessageContext context) {
    Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

    if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {
        //log here
    } else {
        //or here
    }
    return true;
}
```

This works fine, except for the situatin that i call a method without a response. Then the method it only called once instead of twice if there is a response.